# mkdir error: Cannot create directory '' - when trying to start mysql container with docker-compose up

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I'm having a baffling time with docker-compose and mysql.  When I try to start my mysql container with docker-compose, I get an uninformative mkdir error.  My Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml don't even seem to contain a mkdir command for mysql.

Here is configuration:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
db:
  build: docker/mysql
  volumes:
   - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=xxxx
   - MYSQL_USER=xxxx
   - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxx
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxx
  privileged: true
  hostname: "docker.mysql"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:5.6

MAINTAINER "ABC" <developers@abc.com>

ADD my.cnf    /etc/mysql/my.cnf

RUN usermod -u 1000 mysql
RUN usermod -G staff mysql
RUN chown mysql /var/run/mysqld

EXPOSE 3306
```

**my.cnf** *pastebin*

http://pastebin.com/iVSGxhGV

**sudo docker --version**

```
Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108
```

This is a docker setup built by my team mates, so I am not sure what the priviledged:true line is doing, but when I remove it, everything appears to work.

**with privileged:true**

```
sudo docker-compose up db
Creating appname_db_1
Attaching to appname_db_1
db_1 | mkdir: cannot create directory '': No such file or directory
appname_db_1 exited with code 1
```

Once privileged: true is removed, it seems to work.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Have you looked at these? https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7512 and https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/133 - they seem to be similar to what you're seeing.

Comment: Interesting, so this is likely an ubuntu apparmor problem solved by changing docker + mysql's profile.  I haven't actually encountered an apparmor related issue with docker yet, so I didn't suspect it.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Brief update @nwinkler:  So i am working on a OSX machine now and docker-compose can boot everything with no issues.  Have you  any thoughts about why the privileged:true setting seems to cause problems on Ubuntu but not on OSX?